# Installing Ubuntu on my F205TA laptop - a LOT of problems!

Tags: uefi, live-usb, laptop, asus, windows-10

I've been using Windows my whole life, and I really want to test Ubuntu out on my Notebook (ASUS F205TA-BING-FD018BS, Windows 10 installed).

I have tried several options in doing so (installing over USB, SD, rEFInd, easyUEFI, you name it...), but nothing seemed to work. My laptop just skips those options, no matter what I do.

Edit:
Not a duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi), I tried this solution already and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It is not, since i already tried that solution, and it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help with this - I have the X205TA which is the same thing (honestly)

This machine will **only** allow 32-bit UEFI booting. But, you have to use a 64-bit distro image (I know, I know)

Secure boot must be turned off in BIOS as you did already.

You need to edit your live USB. Inside will be a directory `EFI` and inside that a directory `BOOT` That directory must contain the file `bootia32.efi` If it already contains a file with that name, overwrite it with a new one (the one included last time I made a live USB of 16.04 did not work)

[here](https://github.com/hirotakaster/baytail-bootia32.efi/raw/master/bootia32.efi) is a `bootia32.efi` file that recently worked for me (clicking the link will download it)

Drop that file into the right place, and now your USB should boot if it's first in the boot order.

If you still have problems, it might be because of how the USB was made. All that is needed is to format it FAT32, erase everything, and extract the iso onto it. Try [UNetBootIn](https://unetbootin.github.io/) which works fine for other folks. (I use the command line but I don't know how to do it in Windows - if you have access to another Linux system I can help)

You <strike>will</strike> may have issues installing. Please comment and I will support you.

Comment: Hello Zanna. Sadly, it still doesnt work. i Installed the 64bit ISO on my USB with UNetBootIn, palced the file in the folder, and tried it again. Sadly, the USB Drive flashes shortly but nothing happens. Then i just ried the 32 bit one, just to try it. Same result. it just flashes verry shortly and then windows boots up.

Comment: @koenigaxel are you hitting escape after you press the power button to get the boot menu? Have you set BIOS to put usb first in boot order? Have you disabled secure boot?

Comment: I dont know which key exactly gets me into BIOS, so im always spaming some F keys. It does work :P. Big problem here is, that i cant seem to find the USB .... I already tried chosing "Removable Device" in UEFI aswell, but nothing works really. Secure Boot should be off. I'll check on that after work

Comment: @koenigaxel It's F2 for BIOS and escape for boot menu :)

Comment: It seems to be working, i am super impressed.... thank you alot!!!!!

Comment: One more question, the installer told me that "grub-efi-ia32" could not be installed. I will search google for it now. If i dont find anything, ill ask you here and hope for a reply :)

Comment: @koenigaxel now you have a bootable ubuntu system you can use a very nice smart solution... I will get back to you later...

Comment: Okay, now the Installation crashed completely after the grub error. After that it threw me in a live ubuntu and it cant find any network connection devices etc.
i amconfused on what to do next, im gonna keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely a setting in the BIOS preventing anything other than Windows from loading.

I can't tell you exactly which setting to change, but something along the lines of "Allow booting other OS" or "allow non secure-boot OS".

Comment: I tried installing it with secure boot at first, but i red it could lead to problems, so i disabled the secure boot option.
Sadly it had no impact on anything, windows just went up even with 2 boot options which should be valid infront of it.

Comment: Okay, i checked my BIOS, there was no option like you mentioned it. even after updating my bios there was no option still. i am really getting desperate. why is this so hard?

Comment: @koenigaxel So your laptop is refusing to boot from your installation media, correct?

Comment: It seems that way, and its really depressing me.

Comment: @koenigaxel - Have you tried burning it to a DVD?

Comment: Sadly my Laptop doesnt have a DVD slot. all i have is 2 USB 2.0 slots, 1 microSD slot and thats it.

Comment: @koenigaxel - USB is first in the boot order, correct? You could also try the PLOP boot manager: https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html

Comment: Also what tool did you use to burn the ISO to USB?

Comment: I Installed it with pendrivelinux.com Universal USB Installer and also tried it with LiLi USB Creator. I will try PLOP boot manager next, and my boot order is USB, then rEFInd, then windows boot manager.

Answer (score 0):

@koenigaxel try creating the USB installer using Rufus. It has always worked for me, although the process is now very long.

Is it also possible that you are making a 64-bit installer while your computer only would take 32-bit? That happened to me a few months ago.